# Chrome, Firefox, Edge all unable to download a file - but Powershell can?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, dns, powershell

I have a file that is hosted in Azure container storage as a blob. When I try to download the file by pasting the (public) URL into Chrome, I get the error "Failed - Network error" about 1MB into the download.

Suspicion: maybe Chrome doesn't like it?
Nope: tried to download it from any browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge), with or without each browser's Private Browsing mode enabled, all fail shortly into the download.

Suspicion: maybe the networking on my PC is borked?
Nope: tried on 4 other Windows PCs in my house, same failure on all

Suspicion: maybe my home network is borked?
Nope: tried going out and hotspotting from my phone. Same failure

Suspicion: maybe Azure is borked?
Nope: tried from other PCs in other locations  - machines that I can RDP into, friends machines. Even had some help from a Microsoft support person, they were able to successfully download it.

Suspicion: maybe maybe my ISP is borked?
Maybe: both my home network and my phone's hotspot use the same ISP

Further oddness: although no browsers on any machine on my home network are able to download it, I can download it successfully using Powershell's Invoke-WebRequest command

Further troubleshooting: I used Chrome's net-internals to capture an event log from Chrome. chrome-net-export-log.json shows these lines towards the end of the log:

> {"params":{"net_error":-101,"os_error":10054},"phase":0,"source":{"id":9059,"type":8},"time":"895752","type":67},
>   {"params":{"error_lib":33,"error_reason":101,"file":"../../net/socket/socket_bio_adapter.cc","line":120,"net_error":-101,"ssl_error":1},"phase":0,"source":{"id":9059,"type":8},"time":"895752","type":55},
>   {"params":{"description":"Error 101 reading from socket.","net_error":-101},"phase":0,"source":{"id":9063,"type":9},"time":"895752","type":199},
>   {"params":{"description":"Abandoned.","net_error":"ERR_CONNECTION_RESET","stream_id":1},"phase":0,"source":{"id":9051,"type":1},"time":"895753","type":213},

... so it seems that something, somewhere, is just chopping the connection.

I have also tried all sorts of other random things, like clearing all browser history, clearing Chrome's DNS cache, clearing Windows' DNS cache, changing my DNS server, turning IPv6 off/on. No change.

I've also tried connecting to a VPN and then downloading - still fails. So perhaps that's a vote against it being the ISP.

Any suggestions as to how I can troubleshoot further? I will contact my ISP but don't hold out much hope of a resolution there. Any way I can find out which machine on the network is closing the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was indeed an ISP issue. Something in the way that they were peering with Azure caused the borkage. You're welcome everyone else at the same ISP who bewildering failures downloading anything from Azure.